# Cygwin setup (32bit or 64bit) works with the same mirror packages?

Tags: cygwin, installation, package, mirror

I recently installed Cygwin 64-bit (ie. using the setup*64bit.exe) using a specific mirror. It took like 3 hours to download the whole set of packages available from this mirror using this specific setup.exe. Its size is ~6GB.

Now, I want to delete this installation and install the Cygwin 32-bit, it's not a game, it's because some programs are not running well in the 64-bit (don't ask me why, I have no clue).

My question is if I can install with no problems the setup32bit.exe (ie. cygwin 32-bit) with the same set of packages downloaded during my previous installation of the Cygwin 64-bit, or should I run the setup32bit.exe and download the whole set of packages again?

I read [this](http://cygwin.com/install.html) and it seems to me that both share the same public key, but not sure if it will work in the same way for both setup installers.

If I proceed with the installation anyway, in your experience from a programming point of view would that affect the stability of the Cygwin 32-bit?

Any pointers are welcomed, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cygwin setup-x86_64.exe will download 64-bit packages only.